# how to check if root login is disabled on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, root, amazon-lightsail

I tried logging in lightsail instance machine as a root user using the ssh key pair.

The response I received was

> Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than user "root".

I want to know how to check whether login with root is disabled and if it is, how to enable it using ssh keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Ubuntu, for SSH this is configured via SSH server config:
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

in there you should have a row:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

which is what you're looking for.